# Scala appending to a map itera

Tags: scala, yield, for-comprehension

I'm trying to map values from each object of a sequence to a map of two keys to a list, but I'm having some issues getting the correct syntax down.

```
def carConverter(cars: Seq[Car]): Map[(String, Int), List[Car]] = {
for ( car <- cars)
  yield Map[(String,Int), List[Car]] {
  //???
 }
}
```

What I would like to do is iterate through this sequence, map each car's name (car.name) and year (car.year) to the map as two keys, and append the car to the list of cars correlating to this name and year as the value of the Map. I am also trying to not make use of mutable variables here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entries of maps are just tuples, knowing that you can just map over your `Seq[Car]` and create those tuples. After that just call `toMap` and you will get a `Map`:

```
cars.map { car =>
  (car.name, car.year) -> car
}.toMap
```

edit:

If you want to keep duplicates, it is easier to use `groupBy`:

```
cars.groupBy(car => (car.name, car.year))
```

Comment: This has a flaw. The duplicates will be removed but instead they should be appended to the list. Try doing `scala> List(1,1,2,3).map{ x => x -> x}.toMap`

Comment: This seems to be returning a sequence of cars as the value of the map.

Comment: The groupBy method returns as values sequences of cars due to cars being a sequence data structure. How can I convert this to a map?

Comment: Can you maybe post the full code of the Car class and the output of the groupBy?